# JUnit testing in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, anagram

I am trying to learn unit tests in Java so that I can get used to TDD. I have written a simple class with a method that checks 2 words and returns true if the 2nd word is an anagram of the 1st.

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String word, String word2) {

    if(word.length() == word2.length()) {
        // change both words to lowercase incase of any capitals
        String lowerCase1 = word.toLowerCase();
        String lowerCase2 = word2.toLowerCase();
        // create an array of characters for each word
        char[] charArray1 = lowerCase1.toCharArray();
        char[] charArray2 = lowerCase2.toCharArray();
        // sort the arrays in alphabetical order
        Arrays.sort(charArray1);
        Arrays.sort(charArray2);
        // If the 2 arrays match then word is an anagram
        if (Arrays.equals(charArray1, charArray2)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My test then looks like this.

```
    @Test
    public void isAnagram() {
        assertEquals(true, HelloWorld.isAnagram("walk", "alkw"));
    }
```

It works as expected, i.e this code passes, and if I change the second word for example to "alk" it fails.

Is there anything I am missing here? In a real-life scenario, would you also test for exceptions being thrown?

Comment: If you're using TDD, you've got far too much code for that little test. In TDD, everything in code should be there in order to make a test pass. For example, you're checking if the string lengths are equal; but you aren't testing unequal length strings. So... I suggest starting again, and building up your code and test together so you are *actually* doing TDD!

Comment: You should have at least as many tests as there are exit paths from your code.  I see three `return` statements in your code, so I'd expect to find at least three tests - one for each `return`.  I'd also expect to see at least one test around the case insensitivity - for example, test whether `"AbcD"` is an anagram of `"dCBa"`.

Comment: You'll need to test a lot more cases, all in different methods with the `@Test` annotation.  Think of different length strings, empty strings, identical strings, strings where only the case is different, null input.

Comment: If you want to be really robust, you need to consider the locale used when lowercasing. Some letters (e.g. I in Turkish locale) have surprising behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You only tested for the sunshine case. Right away I can think of these other testcases:

1. fails if the two words are not anagrams
2. spaces are ignored
3. case insensitive
4. edge cases like empty strings or null

Answer (score -1):

I have re-factored your example code, and written some unit tests around this code.

I have deliberately created a unit test, where both words have a single space.  This unit test shouldn't pass.

The example code will give you an idea of how you can "exercise" individual methods, with unit tests.

Lots more unit tests can be written.  This is just to give you an idea.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

/**
* Author milesd on 03/02/2021.
*/

public class AnagramTest {

    Anagram valid, diffLength, spaces;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        valid =             new Anagram("tar", "rat");
        diffLength =        new Anagram("tar", "ra");
        spaces =            new Anagram(" ", " ");
    }


    @Test
    public void testIsAnagram() {
        assertTrue(valid.isAnagram());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsAnagramDifferentLengths() {
        assertFalse(diffLength.compareLength());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsAnagramSortAndCompareWithDifferentLengths() {
        assertFalse(diffLength.sortAndCompare());
    }

    // This test passes - spaces are not anagrams
    @Test
    public void testIsAnagramWithSpaces() {
        assertTrue(spaces.compareLength());
        assertTrue(spaces.sortAndCompare());
        assertTrue(spaces.isAnagram());
    }
}

class Anagram {
    private final String word;
    private final String anotherWord;

    Anagram(final String word, final String anotherWord) {
        this.word = word;
        this.anotherWord = anotherWord;
    }

    public boolean compareLength() {
        return word.length() == anotherWord.length();
    }

    public boolean sortAndCompare() {
        final char[] lowerCaseWord = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        final char[] lowerCaseAnotherWord = anotherWord.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(lowerCaseWord);
        Arrays.sort(lowerCaseAnotherWord);
        return Arrays.equals(lowerCaseWord, lowerCaseAnotherWord);
    }

    public boolean isAnagram() {
        return compareLength() && sortAndCompare();
    }
}
```